# Can I attach a view to an animated view?

Tags: android, xml, android-animation

I have a view (ImageView) I would like to animate, and to this image I'm attaching a button. The button is constrained to the image (I'm using a constrained layout) but on animating the image, the button is detached and doesn't participate in the animation.

Is there a simple way to constrain the button to the image so that they both move when animating the image?

I tried to make the button a child of the image:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic2"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/profile_pic_reorder_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_pic_reorder_size"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/profile_pic2">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/deletePic2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/delete_picture_button_size"
            android:background="@drawable/delete_button"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/profilePic2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/profilePic2" />
    </ImageView>
```

But then the button disappears, apparently underneath the image. Is there a simple solution, other than creating a separate animation for the button?

Comment: You can try to put ImageView and Button in common container, FrameLayout, for example and run your animation on container.

Comment: How do you animate your imageView?

Comment: @Bracadabra that sounds like a reasonable solution unfortunately I will have to recreate my layout but thanks anyways

Comment: @AHoneyBustard I'm using the ObjectAnimator class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a (transparent) [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView) inside your ConstraintLayout, put your Image and Button inside the CardView and animate the CardView.